# Discord.py (Rewrite) How to get cooldowns working with on_message event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to convert my commands to on_message events as in this case, it saves up space and it is cleaner to look at. However I can't seem to use @cooldown() anymore as I have to use commands.Cog.listener()

Is there any other way to get a cooldown working? My code is listed below

```
# Cog on_message for waifus and husbandos
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    # Cooldown NOT WORKING
    @cooldown(1, 1, BucketType.user)
    async def on_message(self, message):

        # Defining the channel and global variables
        global waifu_split_msg
        global husbando_split_msg
        channel = message.channel

        # Defining the message content in lowercase
        user_msg = message.content.lower()

        # Defining array for the list of waifus/husbando's available
        waifu_array = ["toga", "yumeko"]
        husbando_array = ["husk", "kakashi", "tamaki"]

        # If the channel that the command has been sent is in the list of accepted channels
        if str(channel) in settings.channels:

            # Surround with try/except to catch any exceptions that may occur
            try:

                # Makes sure that the user wants a random image of a waifu
                if 'w random' in user_msg:

                    # Get embed from randomWaifu() and send it to the channel
                    embed = randomWaifu(message, waifu_array)
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)

                # Makes sure that the user wants a specific image of a waifu
                elif user_msg.startswith('~w'):

                    # Define who the waifu is using string splitting
                    waifu_split_msg = user_msg.split("w ", 1)
                    w_array = str(waifu_split_msg[-1]).lower()

                    # Retrieve the image of the waifu that the user has specified
                    with open(f'images/AnimeImages/Waifus/{w_array}.txt') as file:
                        images_array = file.readlines()

                    # Get the full name of the waifu
                    full_name = Abbrev(w_array)

                    # Get the embed from a displayAnimeImage() and send it to the channel
                    embed = displayAnimeImage(images_array, message, full_name)
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)

            except FileNotFoundError as e:
                print(e)

                # Throw error message saying no waifu's could be found
                await channel.send(f"Sorry! That Waifu doesn't exist!! Try the Waifu's listed below!")

                # Send list of suitable waifu's to the channel
                nice = string.capwords(', '.join(map(str, waifu_array)))
                await channel.send(nice)

            # Surround with try/except to catch any exceptions that may occur
            try:

                # Makes sure that the user wants a random image of a husbando
                if 'h random' in user_msg:

                    # Get embed from randomHusbando() and send it to the channel
                    embed = randomHusbando(message, husbando_array)
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)

                # Makes sure that the user wants a specific image of a husbando
                elif user_msg.startswith('~h'):

                    # Define who the husbando is using string splitting
                    husbando_split_msg = user_msg.split("h ", 1)
                    h_array = str(husbando_split_msg[-1]).lower()

                    # Retrieve the image of the Husbando that the user has specified
                    with open(f'images/AnimeImages/Husbandos/{h_array}.txt') as file:
                        images_array = file.readlines()

                    # Get the full name of the husbando
                    full_name = Abbrev(h_array)

                    # Get the embed from a displayAnimeImage() and send it to the channel
                    embed = displayAnimeImage(images_array, message, full_name)
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)

            except FileNotFoundError as e:
                print(e)

                # Throw error message saying no husbando's could be found
                await channel.send(f"Sorry! That Husbando doesn't exist!! Try the Husbando's listed below!")

                # Send list of suitable Husbando's to the channel
                nice = string.capwords(', '.join(map(str, husbando_array)))
                await channel.send(nice)

        # if the message is outwith the enso-chan-commands
        else:
            # Makes sure that the user only typed ~w or ~h
            if user_msg.endswith('~w') or user_msg.endswith('~h'):
                # Send error message
                message = await channel.send(error_function())

                # Let the user read the message for 2.5 seconds
                await asyncio.sleep(2.5)
                # Delete the message
                await message.delete()
```

The code works perfectly besides the fact that the cooldown() at the top does not have an effect on the event whatsoever

Can anyone help me come up with another solution to this?

Comment: As to why your cooldown is no longer working: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown `A decorator that adds a cooldown to a Command or its subclasses.` That's not a command (a command is invoked on Discord with e.g. `!help`). What you have is a `listener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the amount of times an event is used by using a time parameter or a count parameter. You won't be able to do it per user very easily. If you're wanting a cooldown per user, I would highly recommend switching back to a command approach.
This may help.
[How can I limit the on_message replies (Discord Python bot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503897/how-can-i-limit-the-on-message-replies-discord-python-bot/62504583#62504583)