# (discord.py) Make Bot only react to on_message() every x seconds

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my Discord bot able to tells users to go to sleep when they are up late, which I'm doing by:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now_hour = now.hour                                      #Gets current time in hours.
    if message.author != client.user and now_hour<6:        #Runs if the message is not sent by the bot or if the time is between 00:00 and 06:00
        await message.channel.send('Are you still awake? You ought to go to bed immediately!')
    await client.process_commands(message)                   #If not included, on_message() will override commands
```

But currently it replies to every message in that time period, which is annoying. I know there is cooldowns for commands, but I have not been able to find a similar thing for events. 
**So my question is**: Is there a cooldown equivalent for events, or another smart way of doing so?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the rookie mistakes I've ought to have made.

Comment: You might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503897/how-can-i-limit-the-on-message-replies-discord-python-bot)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the smart way is to use a database to store user information and last message they sent. Then you calculate the time saved to the current time and if the saved time is passed a certain time tell them to go sleep.